# How to generate code for a XExpression subtype?

Tags: xtext, xbase

I have a simple DSL that should generate async code for expressions (this is the simplest example I could come up with to illustrate my point). I just added to the [scripting example](https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext/blob/master/languages/org.xtext.scripting/src/org/xtext/scripting/Scripting.xtext) an new `async` statement:

```
grammar org.xtext.scripting.Scripting with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate scripting "http://www.xtext.org/scripting/Scripting"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase

Script returns xbase::XBlockExpression:
    {Script}
    (expressions+=XExpressionOrVarDeclaration ';'?)*;

XExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
    super | Async
;

Async:
    'async' expression=XExpression
;
```

The idea would be that the `async` code is executed in another thread.

My question is, how can I generate code for the `Async.expression` using the [`ScriptingJvmModelInferrer`](https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext/blob/master/languages/org.xtext.scripting/src/org/xtext/scripting/jvmmodel/ScriptingJvmModelInferrer.xtend)?

In the simplest case I would just wrap the code from the `Async.expression` like this?

```
    AsyncRunner.exec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // the Async.expression would end up here
        }
    })
```

Where is the hook to do that?

Comment: I think I have found an example in https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/207_template.html (Template Language) see the section *Extending the Compiler*

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 3 changes:

1. Extend the compiler to deal with your language. The key point is to handle the `Async` expression.

   ```java
   class ScriptingCompiler extends XbaseCompiler {

       override protected doInternalToJavaStatement(XExpression expr, ITreeAppendable it, boolean isReferenced) {
           switch expr {
               Async : {
                   newLine
                   append('''
                       AsyncRunner.exec(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {''')
                   expr.expression.doInternalToJavaStatement(it, false)
                   newLine
                   append('}});')

               }

               default :
                   super.doInternalToJavaStatement(expr, it, isReferenced)
           }
       }

       override protected internalToConvertedExpression(XExpression obj, ITreeAppendable it) {
           if (hasName(obj))
               append(getName(obj))
           else 
               super.internalToConvertedExpression(obj, it) 
       }
   }
   ```
2. The type of the expression has to be specified

   ```java
   class ScriptingTypeComputer extends XbaseWithAnnotationsTypeComputer {

       override computeTypes(XExpression expression, ITypeComputationState state) {
           if(expression instanceof Async) {
               super.computeTypes(expression.expression, state);
           } else {
               super.computeTypes(expression, state)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Both extensions have to be injected:

   ```java
   class ScriptingRuntimeModule extends AbstractScriptingRuntimeModule {
       def Class<? extends XbaseCompiler> bindXbaseCompiler() {
           return ScriptingCompiler
       }

       def Class<? extends ITypeComputer> bindITypeComputer() {
           return ScriptingTypeComputer
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you extend Xbase you ususally don't apapt the JvmModelInferrer for Compilation but you extend `XbaseTypeComputer` and `XbaseCompiler.doInternalToJavaStatement/internalToConvertedExpression` (depending on what you actually introduce)